# Batch file value in variable

Tags: batch-file

I tried scripting.

```
SET variable=command
```

I expected in variable return string of command. If I build condition like that

```
IF %variable%==expected string doSomething
```

I'm not sure what I saw. It was like %variable% contained command and command was executed, but if I typed in command line %variable% I saw expected string.

I would glad for explanation.

Comment: To capture the return string of a command, use a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)...

Comment: Question: if you do this: `set variable=any string`, how the Batch processor could know that `any string` is or is not a command that should be executed? Answer: it don't knows, so you must explicitly execute the "string" as a command and take its output...

Comment: @Aacini, thank you for explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF "%variable%"=="expected string" doSomething
```

The quotes make the value enclosed appear as a single token.